# How is this expression expanded?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I was going through the following article where i was struggling to understand how an equation is expanded.  I have highlighted the equation in blue coloured rectangle. I tried expanding using `(a-b)^2` formula but i was not getting same as the article has mentioned. Please help

http://hmkcode.github.io/ai/backpropagation-step-by-step/

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what needs to be done here. Why did you use consider using $(a-b)^2$? I don't see any squared terms in there ...

Comment: $\frac{\partial (x - a)^n}{\partial x} = n (x-a)^{n-1}\times\frac{\partial (x - a)}{\partial x} = n (x-a)^{n-1} \times 1 = n (x-a)^{n-1}$.

Comment: @MattiP. Notice the second line it has a squared term there 1/2(prediction-actual)^2